# draw circle around data in a grid (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I have 100 data points scattered within a region. Now I divided the region with 6x6 equisized grids and now it looks like according the figure below:

[figure http://s2.postimg.org/c6zk68myf/IGN2.png](http://s2.postimg.org/c6zk68myf/IGN2.png)

Now I need to to draw a circle within a box of a grid so that I could group points in a box if there is more than 1 point. If this is the case, there shall be no circle within a box if there are none or one points in a box.

Any idea on what I should do?

Here is my MATLAB code for the plot I created above:

```
xm=100;
ym=100;

%x and y Coordinates of the Sink
sink.x=0.5*xm;
sink.y=0.5*ym;

%Number of Nodes in the field
n=100

figure(1);
for i=1:1:n
    S(i).xd=rand(1,1)*xm;
    XR(i)=S(i).xd;
    S(i).yd=rand(1,1)*ym;
    YR(i)=S(i).yd;
    S(i).G=0;
    %initially there are no cluster heads only nodes
    S(i).type='N';

        plot(S(i).xd,S(i).yd,'o');
        hold on;

   
end
NrGrid = 6;   
                               % Number Of Grids
x = linspace(0, 100, NrGrid+1);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x);
S(n+1).xd=sink.x;
S(n+1).yd=sink.y;
plot(S(n+1).xd,S(n+1).yd,'x',X,Y,'k');
 hold on
plot(Y,X,'k')
    set(gca, 'Box','off', 'XTick',[], 'YTick',[])
axis square
        
%First Iteration
figure(1);
```

Expected result:

http://i.share.pho.to/27ae061b_o.jpeg

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm having a hard time understanding what you want.  What exactly do you want done?  What do you mean by draw a circle within a box?  Aren't you already doing this?

Comment: Sorry for my any misleading interpretation. actually I want to group points those are adjacent to each other. i,e in a box if there more points i.e. more than one points then i would like to cover all points in a circle within a box..

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't get it.  How do you define whether points are close to each other?  What do we do with these grouped points?  Maybe you could show us an image of what your expected output looks like?

Comment: here is the sample image http://pho.to/9460P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the proccess you need to go to get there is the following:

1. Get in which grid the points are
2. Compute the minimum radius circle (I used [this FEX submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34767-a-suite-of-minimal-bounding-objects), you can do it yourself or check how it is performed in the PDF that comes with it)
3. Plot the circles

So here there is a piece of code that does 1-2

```
%% Where are the points?
% I am not going to modify your `S` variable, but you could do this inside
% it
points=[S(1:end-1).xd; S(1:end-1).yd];
gridind=zeros(size(points,2),1);
Grid=NrGrid^2;
for ii=1:NrGrid
    for jj=1:NrGrid
        % get points in the current square
        ind=points(1,:)>X(1,ii)& points(1,:)<X(1,ii+1)...
             & points(2,:)>Y(jj,1)& points(2,:)<Y(jj+1,1);
        % save index
        gridind(ind)=(ii-1)*NrGrid+(jj-1)+1;
    end
end

% now that we know in wich grid each point is lets find out wich ones are
% not
c=zeros(NrGrid^2,2);
r=zeros(NrGrid^2,1);

for ii=1:NrGrid^2
    if sum(gridind==ii)>1
        [c(ii,:), r(ii)] = minboundcircle(points(1,gridind==ii),points(2,gridind==ii));

    else
        c(ii,:)=nan;
        r(ii)=nan;
    end
end
```

and here a piece of code that plots them

```
theta=linspace(0,2*pi,20);

offs=1; % For beauty purposes
for ii=1:NrGrid^2
    if ~isnan(c(ii))
        xc=(r(ii)+offs).*cos(theta)+c(ii,1);
        yc=(r(ii)+offs).*sin(theta)+c(ii,2);
        plot(xc,yc,'r');
    end
end

axis([min(X(:)) max(X(:)) min(Y(:)) max(Y(:)) ])
```

Result:

[image]

You could easily draw ellipses changing a bit the code, using for example [this FEX submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3215-fit-ellipse).

Ask if you don't understand something, but should be straightforward.

Comment: where I need to make change, if i want to mark any one point in red color in each circle

Comment: @user38375 I apologise, I dont understand whaat you mean. Can you explain more?